# Generating 2-dimension array in PHP with SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, csv

looking for generating a multi-dimensional array in php (2 for now, more later) with SQL query results, in order to push it in a CSV file later. I want each line "each member" to contain 2 rows, "name" and "surname".

I'm trying this:

```html
$table_echo ="";

$sql='SELECT * FROM members;
$nb = $bdd->query($sql);

while($result = $nb->fetch()){
  $table_echo.= array($result['name'],$result['surname']).",";
}

$data = array(
    $table_echo
);
```

inspired from the following example (w3schools.com):

```html
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );
```

SQL is OK, so do the CSV file generator (tested and working with the $cars array example), but the output CSV file is empty with the first code. What am I getting wrong? Can I use a "while" inside the $data array definition ? Is there an other way to do this? Thanks

Comment: what you have wrong here is you are trying to build the data "visualy" - you see it is written in some way and you are trying to reproduce the syntax through strings. It has different meaning for the PHP interpreter due to the order of processing and meaning. You need to build the data structures dynamicaly through language syntax, not through string representation of that syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create array if your purpose only is to save a file as CSV.

```
//open csv file - if not exists will create new file
$csv_file = fopen('output.csv', "w");

$sql='SELECT * FROM members';
$nb = $bdd->query($sql);

while($result = $nb->fetch()){
  //prepare line
  $line = $result['name'].",".$result['surname'])."\n";
  //write line to csv file
  fwrite($csv_file, $line);
}

fclose($csv_file);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I will use variables from the car example for better understanding

```
$cars = array();
// ... sql
while($result = $nb->fetch()){
  $cars[] = array($result['name'],$result['surname']);
}
// here you have $cars full of data in "correct" structure
```

this should build the same structure as the cars example

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but it doesn't work, in the CSV file I'm only getting one line which is: "ArrayArray | Array | Array", and the "members" table has 10 entries in my database.

Comment: please edit the post with the code you work with csv

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
$table_echo ="";

$sql='SELECT * FROM members';
$nb = $bdd->query($sql);

$data = [];
while($result = $nb->fetch()){
  $data []= array($result['name'],$result['surname']);
}
```